# Database design for IoT application

Tags: sql-server, database-design, iot, database-performance

Our application shows near-real-time IoT data (up to 5 minute intervals) for our customers' remote equipment.

The original pilot project stores every device reading for all time, in a simple "Measurements" table on a SQL Server 2008 database.
The table looks something like this:

`Measurements: (DeviceId, Property, Value, DateTime)`.

Within a year or two, there will be maybe 100,000 records in the table per device, with the queries typically falling into two categories:

- "Device latest value" (95% of queries): looking at the latest value only
- "Device daily snapshot" (5% of queries): looking at a single representative value for each day

We are now expanding to 5000 devices.  The `Measurements` table is small now, but will quickly get to half a billion records or so, for just those 5000 devices.

The application is very read-intensive, with frequently-run queries looking at the "Device latest values" in particular.

**[EDIT #1: To make it less opinion-based]**

### What database design techniques can we use to optimise for fast reads of the "latest" IoT values, given a big table with years worth of "historic" IoT values?

One suggestion from our team was to store `MeasurementLatest` and `MeasurementHistory` as two separate tables.

**[EDIT #2: In response to feedback]**

In our test database, seeded with 50 million records, and with the following index applied:

`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Measurement_DeviceId_DateTime] ON Measurement (DeviceId ASC, DateTime DESC)`

a typical "get device latest values" query (e.g. below) still takes more than 4,000 ms to execute, which is way too slow for our needs:

```
SELECT DeviceId, Property, Value, DateTime
FROM Measurements m
WHERE m.DateTime = (
  SELECT MAX(DateTime) 
  FROM Measurements m2
  WHERE m2.DeviceId = m.DeviceId)
```

Comment: Its still too broad though, there isn't a single answer to your question (which is the premise of SO), there are multiple possibilities each of which could work well to solve the problem. And in fact there is nothing to suggest that your current design, with the correct indexes etc will perform badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question - and as such, it's unlikely you'll get a definitive answer.

However, I have been in a similar situation, and I'll run through my thinking and eventual approach. In summary though - I did option B but in a way to mirror option A: I used a filtered index to 'mimic' the separate smaller table.

My original thinking was to have two tables - one with the 'latest data only' for most reporting, then a table with all historical values. An alternate was to have two tables - one with all records, and one with just the latest.

When inserting a new row, it would typically need to therefore update at least two rows, if not more (depending on how it's stored).

Instead, I went for a slightly different route

- Put all the data into one table
- On that one table, add a new column 'Latest_Flag' (bit, NOT NULL, DEFAULT 1). If it's 1 then it's the latest value; otherwise it's historical
- Have a [filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) on the table that has all columns (with appropriate column order) and filter of Latest_Flag = 1

  - This filtered index is similar to a second copy of the table with just the latest rows only
- The insert process therefore has two steps in a transaction

  - 'Unflag' the last Latest_Flag for that device, etc
  - Insert the new row

It still makes the writes a bit slower (as it needs to do several row updates as well as index updates) but fundamentally it does the pre-calculation for later reads.

When reading from the table, however, you need to then specify `WHERE Latest_Flag = 1`. Alternatively, you may want to put it into a view or similar.

For the filtered index, it may be something like

```
CREATE INDEX ix_measurements_deviceproperty_latest 
    ON Measurements (DeviceId, Property)
    INCLUDE (Value, DateTime, Latest_Flag)
    WHERE (Latest_Flag = 1)
```

Note - another version of this can be done in a trigger e.g., when inserting a new row, it invalidates (sets Latest_Flag = 0) any previous rows. It means you don't need to do the two-step inserts; but you do then rely on business/processing logic being within triggers.

Comment: Thanks @seanb - I haven't heard of filtered indexes before - they're ideal for this scenario.